# extract specific 10 bytes of data from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, find, counter

I need to extract this block of data(assume = " **FF D8** E1 46 1D 01 EC 01 00 00 ")from a numpy array(taken from .h5 file). The start of the frame is **"FF D8"** and the rest varies. There are approximately 5,00,000 data starting with **"FF D8"** and mixed with other data's. I need to identify the start of the sequence and save the next 10 bytes into a file.

```
Code:

import h5py
import numpy as np
import sys
import time
import os
from collections import Counter

hdf5_file_name = r"name.h5"
dataset_name = 'IMG_Data_0'
file = h5py.File(hdf5_file_name,'r+')
dataset = file[dataset_name]

file.visititems(lambda name,obj:print(name, obj)) #to see detailed structure     of hdf5 file

print('Length of IMG_Data_0 is: ',len(dataset))
dec_array = data.flatten() # combines multi-dimensional aary to 1D
hex_array = [hex(x)[2:] for x in b] #converts from decimal to hexa decimal
```

I have converted to hexadecimal values. Now I need to extract the sequences.Later from **FF D8** E1 46 1D 01 EC 01 00 00 ", I need to check the proper functionality of counter , **1D**.That is: I will get the sequences like                                  FF D8 E1 46 1D **01** EC 01 00 00
    FF D8 E1 46 1D **02** EC 01 00 00
    FF D8 E1 46 1D **03** EC 01 00 00
    FF D8 E1 46 1D **04** EC 01 00 00 it counts till it reache 1D.
Thank you

Comment: Could you post code for your best attempt? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to parse the *.h5 file directly? (You should probably use [h5py](http://www.h5py.org/) instead.) Or is it the content of the h5 dataset?

Comment: Yes I need the data from the content of the h5 datasheet.Thank you